# NSMutableArray insertObject not adding into array

Tags: ios, arrays

I'm trying to addobjects to a nsmutable array in lion, xcode 4.3 using ARC. the following is causing the program to crash with SIGABRT

```
 NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
 [myArray insertObject:@"Hello World" AtIndex:5]
```

how can i add custom objects to any index in the array?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `NSArray` in the same manner of C fixed-size array, I suggest you fill the `NSArray` instance with as many `[NSNull null]` as you want for array size, e.g. 10 items in this case.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [myArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

And when you want to insert object, use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` instead. The size of the array won't change.

```
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@"Hello World"];
```

You also need to check against [NSNull null] when accessing item.

```
id item = [myArray objectAtIndex:5];
if (item != [NSNull null]) {
    NSString* stringItem = item;
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While your array **capacity** is 10, your array **size** right after creation is 0, so you can't insert element at index 5 because it's out of bounds.

Also, you can't insert `nil` into an array, but if you want to have an array with 10 nil elements as placeholders, you might use `NSNull`:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    [myArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

// then this would work, but it inserts a new element, so your array size will be 11
// [myArray insertObject:@"Hello World" atIndex:5]
// to keep array size at 10 use this method:
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:@"Hello World"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have fix number of elements in array then use NSArray. Then you will able to set object for particular position. when you are using  NSMutableArray, its size is 0. you have to have min 5 elements to insert at 5th position in NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert object in an empty array, which wont work. Instead, try to add object. Try this...

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[myArray addObject:@"Hello World"];
```